# returning a std::list from a function

Tags: c++, list, prime-factoring

I've been given an assignment to build the following function template "list primeFactors(unsigned long int n)". The function returns a list of integers of the prime factorization of a natural number. I've created a program that can prime factorization but I'm having issues using a list.

```
#include <list>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


using namespace std;


list<unsigned long int> primeFactors(unsigned long int n)
{
    list<unsigned long int> list;

    for (unsigned long int i=2; i <=n; i++)
    {
        while(n % i == 0)
        {
            n /= i;
            //cout << i << " ";
            list.push_back(i);
        }
        return list;
    }

}

int main()
{
    unsigned long int n;
    list<unsigned long int> plist;
    cout << "Enter num: " <<endl;
    cin>>n;
    plist = primeFactors(n);

    for(list<unsigned long int>::iterator it=plist.begin(); it != plist.end(); ++it)
    {
        cout << ' ' << *it;
        cout << '\n ';
    }


    return 0;
}
```

My program is no longer returning the correct numbers of the factorization and I'm unsure what the issue is.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `return list;` quits out of the function at the first iteration of `for`

Comment: @Valentin The entire first `while` loop goes correctly, but it quits after that in the first iteration of `for`.

Comment: Show the input and output.

Comment: Besides the `return` issue, you also have another error: `cout << '\n ';` which should generate a compiler warning *warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]* for the extra space after newline. Just change to `for(auto it : plist) { cout << it << '\n'; }`.

Answer (score 2):

This likely has nothing to do with returning the list. The problem is you always return it before finishing your iterations:

```
for (unsigned long int i=2; i <=n; i++)
{
    while(n % i == 0)
    {
        n /= i;
        //cout << i << " ";
        list.push_back(i);
    }
    return list; // I think you meant to put this outside the for loop
}
// Probably here is better for the return.
```

Try using a debugger next time, you will see this issue much more quickly then posting here.

Comment: Putting the return list outside the the loop doesn't fix the issue. It's still returning wrong information and I'm using gedit on linux as part of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the list outside the for loop

Comment: While this _probably_ is a good suggestion a few more elaborating words might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Line `return list;` is too early. Move it beyond the curly brace.